# run docker container as root

Tags: linux, permissions, docker, libreelec

I am running transmission on libreelec / rpi3 with docker

created with

```
    docker create --name=transmission \
    --restart=always \
    -v /storage/docker/transmission/config:/config \
    -v /media:/media \
    -p 9091:9091 -p 51413:51413 \
    -p 51413:51413/udp \
    --user=0:0 \
    linuxserver/transmission
```

however when I see who runs the transmission process I get

```
#ps -ef | grep trans
    2611 root      0:00 s6-supervise transmission
    2619 911       0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -g /config -c /watch -f
```

I know transmission doesn't run as root cause it gets a lot of 'access denied' 
feels like I am missing something very simple 
I tried "-u 0:0" "-u=0:0" "-u 0" "-u=0" cause It wasn't clear if I need the equal sign or space, all failed :(

Comment: It's unclear where you're seeing those errors but reading the [information on the image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/transmission/) you probably want to use PUID and/or PGID.

Comment: @Seth - thanks ! was missing that, works I knew it was something stupid, too bad I can't accept your comment as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Seth has pointed out - this image uses its own property for user/group:

```
    docker create --name=transmission \
    --restart=always \
    -v /storage/docker/transmission/config:/config \
    -v /media:/media \
    -p 9091:9091 -p 51413:51413 \
    -p 51413:51413/udp \
    -e PUID=0 -e PGID=0 \
    linuxserver/transmission
```

did the job

Thanks!